# Sending same information from UDP server to all clients at a time without using Broadcast

Tags: c, windows, winapi, network-programming, udp

I want to send same information after specific time intervals from UDP server to all clients at a time without using Broadcast. 
For this purpose, I am thinking of adding information of each Client which tries to communicate with the Server in some sort of text file, and then, when I want to send a single message to all connected Clients, I'll pick up IP addresses saved in the text file and will send data at those addresses only. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: What is the nature of your clients?  Local, global, mobile?

Comment: Clients are predefined, i.e. only Clients with IP Addresses present in DataBase can communicate to Server.

Comment: It matters whether or not they are on your local network, whether they have fixed IP addresses, and what the firewall/NAT situation is between your server and the clients.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to send same information after specific time intervals from UDP server to all clients at a time without using Broadcast.

Then you have to use multicast. There is no other way to satisfy the 'at the same time' requirement.

> Is this a correct approach?

No. Nothing that does one send to one client at a time satisfies your stated requirement.

Multicast is also a lot simpler than trying to implement it all yourself.